# if (fileUploadContract.HasFile) is returning null

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a file upload control which keeps returning null no matter what

```
<div visible="false" id="divUpload" runat="server" class="divPadded">
     <div class="DivContracts">
        <div class="divPad">
            <asp:FileUpload id="fileUploadContract" runat="server" />
        </div>
```

code behind

```
 protected void btnSaveContract_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

  if (fileUploadContract.HasFile)


.....
```

the page constantly posts back because the original code is in a view
so i tried throwing this into the page load and this also shows null:

```
if (Session["UploadedFile"] == null && fileUploadContract.HasFile)
                Session["UploadedFile"] = fileUploadContract;
            else if (Session["UploadedFile"] != null && (!fileUploadContract.HasFile))
                fileUploadContract = (FileUpload)Session["fileUploadContract"];
            else if (fileUploadContract.HasFile)
                Session["UploadedFile"] = fileUploadContract;
```

Comment: This seems an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). to me... But you are adding a Control to the Session, not the "content" of that control, that being the file itself. That will not survive the page life cycle. You will have to store the file directly and save a reference to that file in the Session, or fix the original issue: `the page constantly posts back`

Comment: i can not modify that "page constantly post back" because that would require a rewrite of the entire application since it is all connected.  That session was to see if the file upload had a file during post back-- it does not maintain said file or control during the postback

Comment: Why not store the file on the first file upload postback in a temp folder and save a reference in a Session.

Comment: Are you using a update panel? Remember, the standard HTML file upload control requires a FULL PAGE post back before the .HasFile can be used. If you using a update panel, then that prevents a full page post back which of course means the FileUpLoad control can't be used inside of a update panel. Remember, you can only grab the file and can ONLY use .HasFile on the 1st post-back, after that, the FileUpLoad control is now empty since the file been up-load on first post-back. You can't have multiple post-backs - you ONLY get the file on the first post-back since the file been selected.

Comment: You are free to set session that a file has been up-loaded, but the file IS REALLY uploaded on ANY post-back. ONCE the file upload control has selected a file. So, if you have a file, you MUST save the file, and then of course you can set a session value to that fact. However, the post-back is when the file is uploaded, and once the file is uploaded, then the status of the FileUpLoad control is now re-set, and can even be used to upload another file. The simple matter is if/when the user selects a file, then it is up-loaded on next post back. Alternatives is upload control without post-back

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal  it looks like the entire page is in an updatepanel with views inside.  The control i am messing with is inside the update panel.

Comment: Ok, then see my post below for some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, as noted the issue becomes that the standard FileUpLoad control is a "one time" kind of deal. This means that any post-back will ALSO up-load the file.

And on top of above, this means the standard file upload control REQUIRES a post-back for it to work. If you adopt an update panel? Well, the WHOLE idea of an update panel is to prevent a full page post-back in the first place! And by preventing a full-page post-back, then you taken off the table use of the FileUpLoad control in an update panel. Thus, FileUpLoad control can't be used in an update panel due to the update panel very existence and "job in life" is to prevent a full-page post back.

There are several solutions, but probably the best solution is to adopt a "ajax" file upload control. They are rather nice, since such "ajax" file upload controls don't require a post-back.

So, say this setup with 2 update panels:

```
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" 
            runat="server" 
            style="float:left;width:400px;border-color:black;border:solid;padding:10px"
            UpdateMode="Conditional"
             >
            <ContentTemplate>

                <h3>My Update panel with button</h3>
                <asp:Button ID="cmdAddOne" runat="server" Text="Add + 1 to label"
                    OnClick="cmdAddOne_Click"/>
                <br />
                Count = <asp:Label ID="lblNum" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label>

            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>

        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server"
            style="float:left;width:400px;border-color:black;border:solid;padding:10px;margin-left:30px"
            UpdateMode="Conditional"
            >
            <ContentTemplate>
                <h3>Select file(s) to upload</h3>
                <ajaxToolkit:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload1" runat="server" />

            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Now the result is this:

[image]

So, note how my file upload control does not care about a post-back, since it does not need nor require a post-back.

Thus, I can click on buttons on the left side update panel.

The code for the left side button click is this:

```
    protected void cmdAddOne_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int MyCounter = Convert.ToInt32(lblNum.Text);
        MyCounter += 1;
        lblNum.Text = MyCounter.ToString();
    }
```

And note how that button click does NOT clear the list of files I selected in the right side update panel. As noted, this works since the upload control I'm using does not require a post back, and thus the AjaxFileUpLoad control works fine when placed inside of a update panel.

And I am free to select, upload, or even up-load multiple times in the right-side update panel. And the reason why all this works is that I am using a "ajax" file up-load control. Such controls don't require a post-back, and better yet, they tend to provide a "drag + drop" hot spot. They provide a progress bar (so it does not look like the browser has frozen during an upload). And such controls also allow un-limited file up-load size since they are "chunked" and up-load in files in small bite sized chunks.

Now the above example AjaxFileUpLoad is from the free AjaxToolKit. There are others for free, and file pond and a few others come to mind.

So, adopting a ajax enabled up-load control will eliminate the requirement for a post-back to upload files. And as above shows, we are free to select a few files, click on the button in the other update panel, and then go back to the upload control and update panel, and independently select more files, or upload files.

To be fair, adopting the whole "big" AjaxToolKit for just the one file up-load control is an Ajax Toolkit bit much, but there are other useful controls in the AJ toolkit such as a HTML editor, and a nice "auto complete" as you type.

The free AjaxToolKit is maintained by the fine folks from Dev Express.

You can find the AjaxToolKit here:

https://www.devexpress.com/Products/AJAX-Control-Toolkit/

Quite sure you can also install with NuGet. As noted, there are quite a few choices here, but at the end of the day introduction of a good file upload system should become part of your "tool bag" of choices.